# How to convert between android camera timestamp and system time?

Tags: android, time, timestamp

In my Android project with camera2 interface, I used `AImage_getTimestamp()` to get the timestamp of each picture. But this timestamp is different from my system time got with `clock_gettime()`. But I truly need to use these two time together to get some work.

I could understand these two times are within different architectures, but can I convert them to each other? Or to say, can I get the system time when a camera picture's timestamp is created?

For example, camera timestamps are discrete as *ts0*, *ts1*, *ts2*, and *ts3*. In my code, I want to get a **real-time** timestamp *ts0'* at the time some code is executed, which is not exactly *ts0* but *ts0* with a time margin added. How can I get this *ts0'*?

[image]

Comment: Unclear what you are trying to achieve, however have you looked at EXIF data or is that resolution not accurate enough?

Comment: thank you @MorrisonChang, In my app, I need to predict an algorithm running time, and I want to add this running time to real camera timestamp. But these two time are not unified.

Comment: So what `ACAMERA_SENSOR_INFO_TIMESTAMP_SOURCE` are you getting. Ref: https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/camera.html#group___camera_1gga49cf3e5a3deefe079ad036a8fac14627a1f77ba9480a70bc846cfc1f060ff01a1

Comment: @MorrisonChang sorry for my holiday delay, I got `ACAMERA_SENSOR_INFO_TIMESTAMP_SOURCE_REALTIME` as time source.

Answer (score 1):

Your device supports REALTIME camera timestamps. As stated before, your camera timestamps are in the same coordinate system as the elapsed realtime since boot. In your [ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener) you can use the following code:

```
long imageReaderTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos();

Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
long cameraTime = image.getTimestamp();
```

Both timestamps can be compared, and 'imageReaderTime' (the one you are interested in) is slightly larger than 'cameraTime', because the [onImageAvailable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener#onImageAvailable(android.media.ImageReader)) callback takes a small amount of time to inform you about the new image. This also introduces a slight variance.

Eddy Talvala's answer should be accepted.

Comment: how is this camera time related to the camera exposure time? is it count before or after the camera exposure?

Comment: @flankechen It has been a while. I seem to remember it is the start of the exposure window. Eddy Talvala's answer below seems to indicate this as well (see "MONOTONIC").

Answer (score 0):

In general, depending on the value of [TIMESTAMP_SOURCE](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/camera.html#group___camera_1gga49cf3e5a3deefe079ad036a8fac14627a1f77ba9480a70bc846cfc1f060ff01a1), the camera timestamps are either based on CLOCK_MONOTONIC or CLOCK_BOOTTIME.

MONOTONIC is used when SOURCE is UNKNOWN; but there's no guarantee on the quality of synchronization between the camera timestamps and the rest of the system; that is, the actual start of exposure time may be off by quite a few milliseconds.

REALTIME means the timestamps are in the CLOCK_BOOTTIME time base (in the Java SDK, that matches to [SystemClock#elapsedRealtimeNanos](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtimeNanos.). REALTIME timestamps are going to be closely synchronized, so that they can be combined with inertial sensor data (gyros, etc) accurately.

I don't know which kinds of timestamps you're reading from clock_gettime, but the easiest option would be to match the camera's source.  Otherwise, you need to determine the offset between the time you're using and what the camera is using.  The offset won't change during a single camera session, so you can just measure it once at start of camera use.

Comment: thank you eddy, my time source is exactly `ACAMERA_SENSOR_INFO_TIMESTAMP_SOURCE`, but the timestamp are still different from time got with `clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, ...)`

Comment: sorry, `ACAMERA_SENSOR_INFO_TIMESTAMP_SOURCE_REALTIME`